# Ошибка доступа к чтению при создании объекта QChart

Tags: c++, qt

Хочу создать гистограмму, но после добавления QBarSet к QBarSeries

```
series->append(sets);
```

появляется ошибка c:\users\qt\work\install\include\qtcore\qscopedpointer.h:118: ошибка: В отладчике возникла ошибка: Exception at 0x7ffd8497f88a, code: 0xc0000005: read access violation at: 0x11, flags=0x0 (first chance)

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"
#include <cmath>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    hLayout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
    left = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    txt_random = new QTextEdit(this);
    txt_random->setReadOnly(true);
    txt_random->setPlainText("Случайные величины:\n");
    // Инициализация
    a = a0;
    M = 3.1415926535;
    // Выборка
    for (i = 0; i < N; ++i){
        a = modf(a * M, &intptr);
        x[i] = a;
        txt_random->setPlainText(txt_random->toPlainText() + QString::number(x[i]) + "  ");
    }
    center = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    txt_param = new QTextEdit(this);
    left->addWidget(txt_random);
    // Выборочная средняя
    mx = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        mx += x[i];
    mx /= N;
    txt_param->append("Математическое ожидание: 1/2 = 0.5");
    txt_param->append("Выборочное среднее: " + QString::number(mx));
    // Дисперсия
    dx = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        dx += pow(x[i] - mx, 2);
    dx /= N;
    txt_param->append("Дисперсия: 1/12 = 0.0 833");
    txt_param->append("Выборочная дисперсия: " + QString::number(dx));
    center->addWidget(txt_param);
    // Частотная таблица
    h /= Len;
    for (i = 0; i < Len; ++i){
        nk[i] = 0;
        pk[i] = 0;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        for (j = 0; j < Len; ++j)
            if (x[i] < (j + 1) * h && x[i] > j * h){
                nk[j]++;
                break;
            }
    for (i = 0; i < Len; ++i)
        pk[i] = nk[i] / N;

    table = new QTableWidget(Len, 3, this);
    table->setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, new QTableWidgetItem("Интервал"));
    table->setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, new QTableWidgetItem("Количество"));
    table->setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, new QTableWidgetItem("Частота"));
    for (i = 0; i < Len; ++i){
        QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(i*h) + ":" + QString::number((i + 1) * h));
        table->setItem(i, 0, item);
        item = new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(nk[i]));
        table->setItem(i, 1, item);
        item = new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(pk[i]));
        table->setItem(i, 2, item);
    }
    center->addWidget(table);
    // Гистограмма
    for (i = 0; i < Len; ++i){
        sets.append(new QBarSet(QString::number(i*h) + ":" + QString::number((i + 1) * h)));
        color = QColor::fromHslF(currentHue, 0.7, 0.5);
        currentHue += 0.618033988749895f;
        currentHue = std::fmod(currentHue, 1.0f);
        sets[i]->append(nk[i]);
        sets[i]->setColor(color);
    }
    qBar->append(sets);
    chartHoz = new QChart();
    chartHoz->addSeries(qBar);
    chartHoz->setAnimationDuration(QChart::SeriesAnimations);
    axisY->setRange(0,150);
    chartHoz->addAxis(axisY,Qt::AlignLeft);
    qBar->attachAxis(axisY);
    chartHoz->legend()->setVisible(true);
    chartHoz->legend()->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight);
    chartView = new QChartView(chartHoz);
    chartView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    right->addWidget(chartView);
    hLayout->addLayout(left);
    hLayout->addLayout(center);
    setLayout(hLayout);

    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Если убрать создание этого объекта (и соответственно всего, что с ним происходит) то ошибка возникает на строке

```
hLayout->addLayout(left);
```

Чтобы заработало без гистограмм, то приходится убирать из *.pro файла строку QT += charts и убирать из кода все, что связано с charts
Может что-то не правильно в *.pro файле

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets


CONFIG += c++11
QT += charts

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    widget.cpp

HEADERS += \
    widget.h

FORMS += \
    widget.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Прикреплю еще на всякий заголовочный

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QTableWidget>
#include <QtCharts/QChartView>
#include <QtCharts/QBarSeries>
#include <QtCharts/QBarSet>
#include <QtCharts/QLegend>
#include <QtCharts/QBarCategoryAxis>
#include <QtCharts/QValueAxis>
#include <QColor>

using namespace QtCharts;

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class Widget; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

const int N = 1000; // Размер выборки
const double a0 = 0.1;
const int Len = 10; // Число интервалов

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Widget();

private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
    QVBoxLayout *left, *center, *right;
    QHBoxLayout *hLayout;
    QTextEdit *txt_random, *txt_param;
    QTableWidget *table;
    QList<QBarSet *> sets;
    QBarSeries *qBar;
    QChart *chartHoz;
    QValueAxis *axisY;
    QChartView *chartView;
    QColor color;

    double a, M; // Член последовательности
    double intptr;
    int q, k; // Параметры последовательности
    float x[N]; // Массив случайных величин
    float nk[Len]; // Число попаданий в интервал
    float pk[Len]; // Частота попаданий в интервал
    int i, j;
    float mx, dx, h = 1;
    float currentHue = 0.0;
};
#endif // WIDGET_H
```

Comment: right->addWidget(chartView) а ты под right выделил память?

Comment: @Aptem_f, теперь да)) Но ошибка на данный момент не в этом

Comment: Короче говоря, как бы я не добавлял сеты к серии, по одному или списком, вылезает данная ошибка. Сначала считал, что это происходит при создании объекта QCharts, но оказалось, что это не так

Comment: Отладчик при краше показывает строку, которую будет обрабатывать следующей

Comment: @Aptem_f, спасибо, раньше этого не знал))

Answer (score 0):

Простите за ваше время, я забыл выделить память под QBarSeries